# android p APK run time can't find AppCompatViewInflater

Tags: android, product

I have a apk Android O， be place in vendor partition。the apk using AppCompatActivity。Now same code of APK, build in Android P AOSP & put it to product partition, the APK runtime crash：

```
09-14 10:34:07.968  4343  4343 I uamp_MusicPlayerActivi: Activity onCreate
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate: Failed to instantiate custom view inflater androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater. Falling back to default.
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1242)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1313)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:1885)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2599)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2672)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2071)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:573)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:516)
09-14 10:34:07.978  4343  4343 I AppCompatDelegate:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:464)
```

Do the following build & install APK：
1. Install the Android P AOSP build APK to data partition --> crash
2. Using Android studio API 28 build the APK & adb install --> Pass
3. Replace the SDK of Android studio to prebuilts\sdk\28 & build APK in product partition --> carsh

Who meet the same problem?Can you provide your solution? Thansk